# Unknown Column in On Clause (but does exist)

Tags: mysql, sql

I've had a look at some other questions like this but I'm not sure I understand/can apply it here. I know my DB has this column for t and for w as well but it doesn't like either. Can someone please take a look and see if they can figure out the issue? :)

ERROR: Unknown column 't.id_cat' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT
            c.id_cat,
            c.cat_name,
            t.id_type,
            t.type_name,
            t.type_desc,
            t.num_works,
            t.num_comments,
            w.id_work,
            t.child_level,
            w.id_member,
            mg.group_name,
            m.real_name,
            w.work_title,
            w.work_cap,
            u.filetype,
            u.location,
            w.id_feedback,
            w.id_series,
            w.id_triggers,
            w.is_adult,
            w.poster_time,
            w.work_comments,
            w.work_views
        FROM
            smf_works_uploads as u
        LEFT JOIN
            smf_works_works AS w ON (w.id_work = u.id_work)
        LEFT JOIN
            smf_members AS m ON (m.id_member = w.id_member)
        LEFT JOIN
            smf_membergroups AS mg ON (mg.id_group = m.id_group)
        LEFT JOIN
            smf_works_categories AS c ON (c.id_cat = t.id_cat)
        LEFT JOIN
            smf_works_types AS t ON (t.id_type = w.id_type)
        WHERE
            t.id_type = 16
```

Answer (score 4):

Switch the two joins

```
LEFT JOIN
            smf_works_types AS t ON (t.id_type = w.id_type)
LEFT JOIN
            smf_works_categories AS c ON (c.id_cat = t.id_cat)
```

Because you can only use `t` if you already joined the table before.